# oracle tablespace storage option

Tags: oracle, storage

If the extent of the Oracle tablespace is local, the value seems to be ignored even when the query below is executed.

Is this normal?

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TS1_FIXED2
DATAFILE
    '\df1_fixed2.dbf'
        SIZE 1024000
DEFAULT  NOCOMPRESS STORAGE (
    INITIAL 10240
    NEXT 10240
    MINEXTENTS 2
    MAXEXTENTS 50
    PCTINCREASE 50
)
SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT MANUAL
```

| TABLESPACE_NAME | INITIAL | NEXT | MINEXTENTS | MAXEXTENTS | PCTINCREASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TS1_FIXED2 | 65536 | null | 1 | 2147483645 | 2147483645 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is expected.**
The extents of a locally managed tablespace are managed efficiently in the tablespace by the Oracle database server.
However, if it was dictionary-managed tablespace, you could manage extents more
actively. And remember, Oracle does not recommend their use!